# How to disable filtering options in material-ui Autocomplete?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, react-hooks

I'm using material-ui [Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/). When the user changes input, it fetches suggestions from a backend asynchronously. This is part of the code:

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

<Autocomplete
  ...
  freeSolo={true}
  options={options}
  renderInput={params => (
    <TextField
      ...
      {...params}
      onChange={async (e) => {
          // get suggestions from backend
          const suggestions = await getSuggestions(e.target.value);

          // update autocomplete options
          setOptions(suggestions);

          ...
      }}
      InputProps={{
        ...params.InputProps,
        endAdornment: (
          <React.Fragment>
            {loading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} /> : null}
            {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
          </React.Fragment>
        ),
      }}
    />
  )}
/>
```

The problem is that material-ui Autocomplete doesn't show all of the options that are set using "setOptions". It filters them.

for example: Suppose that the user enters "appl" and getSuggestions returns ["apple", "orange", "potato"]. But It only shows "apple" because it filters out "orange" and "potato".

How can I disable filtering?

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of autocomplete? To show you the items that match what the user wrote in the text field?

Comment: You are right. But I want it to be smarter. I want it to show the items that are relevant. @Dekel

Comment: If the data that you have there comes directly from the server and you do the filtering in the server (and not in the autocomplete component) you can use the `freeSolo` option, which tells the Autocomplete component to not do any filtering at all.

Comment: @Dekel Actually I have set freeSolo={true}. It doesn't disable filtering. It just lets the input value to be something other than options.

Comment: Did you try to set the `filterOptions` to just return all the values? `filterOptions={(options, object) => options}`

Comment: Yes Thanks that's it! filterOptions={(options, state) => options}. Please post an answer so that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `filterOptions` method is intended to give you the freedom to decide which options will be available and which will be hidden.

If you just want to show all options - just implement the `filterOptions` to return all the values:

```
filterOptions={(options, state) => options}
```

Comment: It was a bit surprised to see that there was a default filterOptions (even though it makes sense). This tripped me up, as I'm using a typo-tolerant search engine to fetch autocomplete options, whereas Material UI was doing a strict-er comparison and hiding some of the results from the search engine. Thanks for your answer!